# Mysql query between date query

Tags: mysql

I am using this query but it is not selecting the end date data, date `2018-04-07` and `2018-04-08` data selecting but not `2018-04-09`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ticket 
 WHERE created_date >= '2018-04-07'
   AND created_date <= '2018-04-09'
```

Comment: in your table, which formate used to store date?

Comment: type: time stamp and format: 2018-04-10 11:58:30

Comment: Since you don't specify a time part `'00:00:00'` is assumed. Isn't it easier to do `< '2018-04-10'`

Comment: So what is your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ticket` 
WHERE `created_date` >= '2018-04-07 00:00:00:' AND `created_date` <= '2018-04-09 23:59:59'
```